# SQL server -----IF we have lot of records in Database. How we can handle them?

Tags: sql-server

IF we have lot of records in Database. How we can handle them?

Comment: Handle them? What do you mean by that vague word?

Comment: Use the right indices, and tune your SQL queries

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't matter how much data you have, SQL Server will handle itself :).

And if you are talking about performance -

1. Make sure that your are using proper indexes
2. Check your sql queries, they should be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about managing large data in the database tables for this in SQL there is a feature called data partitioning. For this you can check this
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1200

Answer (score -1):

- Shrink your database by schedule
- Check the log file size or delete if unnecessary.